# Analysis Service Tabular model

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssas-tabular

Error while connecting to the work space server in analysis service tabular model

Below the error Image attached...
[image: below the error image attached]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect to a local server or a remote tabular services server?  If it is remote, you need to ensure that firewall rules are allowing traffic to the server.

Comment: Connecting to remote server, When I Turn on the firewalls rules,I'm unable to connect to the Database engine in ssms

Comment: My windows firewall is disabled cause of some admin issues